# When creating JComboBoxes inside a JPanel, is it possible to control the size (specifically the height) of the each JComboBox

Tags: java, javascript, swing, jpanel, jcombobox

I have created a `JPanel` in which I am creating varying numbers of `JComboBoxes`. The number of `JComboBoxes` being put in depends on varying conditions before hand.

The problem I have is that when I create these `JComboBoxes` they automatically fit to the full size of the `JPanel`, please see images below.

[image: enter image description hereImage where just one <code>JComboBox</code> is created which takes up the whole JPanel()]

Is there any way for me to fix the size of this `JComboBox` so it is smaller than the full size of the `JPanel`?

---

FOLLOW UP INFORMATION

---

Thank you for your interest and help

I am using the Netbeans development tool. I first created a JScrollPanel and then put the JPanel inside this JScrollPanel using NetBeans and which creates these in uneditable code in initComponents().

I can provide all the code for this but it is a sizable amount and may not be useful, it begins:

```
    jScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    isotopePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    jScrollPane.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Isotope Details"));

    isotopePanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
    isotopePanel.setAutoscrolls(true);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout isotopePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(isotopePanel);
    isotopePanel.setLayout(isotopePanelLayout);
    isotopePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        isotopePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 755, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    isotopePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        isotopePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 356, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jScrollPane.setViewportView(isotopePanel);

    .....
```

In my code, in aboutToDisplay() I created the JComboBoxe(s) and labels for them in an array called LabelsAndCombos and then put these into the Jpanel using the code:

```
    javax.swing.GroupLayout isotopesLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(isotopePanel);   

    isotopesLayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    isotopesLayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = isotopesLayout.createSequentialGroup();
    javax.swing.GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup = isotopesLayout.createSequentialGroup();

    GroupLayout.ParallelGroup labelGroup = isotopesLayout.createParallelGroup();
    GroupLayout.ParallelGroup comboBoxGroup = isotopesLayout.createParallelGroup();
    for(int i=0;i<calcDef.getAtomLabels().length;i++){
        labelGroup.addComponent(labelsAndCombos[i].label);
        comboBoxGroup.addComponent(labelsAndCombos[i].combo);
        vGroup.addGroup(isotopesLayout.createParallelGroup().addComponent(labelsAndCombos[i].label).addComponent(labelsAndCombos[i].combo));
    }

    hGroup.addGroup(labelGroup);
    hGroup.addGroup(comboBoxGroup);

    isotopesLayout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);
    isotopesLayout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);

    isotopePanel.setLayout(isotopesLayout);
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information to make this clearer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a `GridLayout` to prescribe the size of the elements in your panel. Consider using a different layout within your `JPanel` such as a `GridBagLayout`. For example:

[image: An example of GridBagLayout with a JCombobox that does not vertically resize]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.Insets;


public class IsotopeDetails extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    IsotopeDetails frame = new IsotopeDetails();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public IsotopeDetails() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        JLabel lblIsotopeDetails = new JLabel("Isotope Details");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblIsotopeDetails = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblIsotopeDetails.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_lblIsotopeDetails.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_lblIsotopeDetails.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblIsotopeDetails.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(lblIsotopeDetails, gbc_lblIsotopeDetails);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox.gridx = 1;
        gbc_comboBox.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(comboBox, gbc_comboBox);

        pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: @user3602112 If this answer addresses your question, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to let others know the issue is resolved. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! You are correct, I am using GroupLayout. I am limited in this because I am using the JPanel Form using the Netbeans development tool and so when I create the JPanel it automatically creates the GroupLayout. I know the size of a JComboBox can be changed using the function box.setPreferredSize(size). I can use this to make my JComboBox bigger than the JPanel... but unfortunately not smaller.

Comment: `I am limited in this because I am using the JPanel Form using the Netbeans development tool` - don't use the development tool to create the GUI. Spend time learning Java and how to use layout managers, instead of learning a tool the limits how you write the code. `I know the size of a JComboBox can be changed using the function box.setPreferredSize(size).` - You should NOT use the setPreferredSize() method. It is the job of the component to determine its own preferred size.

Answer (score 0):

Use an appropriate layout manager for your desired layout. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples. Some layout managers respect the size of a component and other don't.

You could still use a `GridLayout` for one panel but then nest that panel in another that uses a `FlowLayout`. Something like:

```
JPanel comboBoxes = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) );
comboBoxes.add( comboBox1 );
comboBoxes.add( comboBox2 );

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add( comboBoxes );

frame.add( wrapper );
```

The layout manager(s) you choose depends on your exact requirements.